# "scala: unreachable code" but no line number or hints?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

Running it from Maven and IntelliJ IDEA both give me the similar terse error. Here is the interesting part of the Maven output:

```
[INFO] Compiling 138 source files ...
[ERROR] error: unreachable code
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Not getting any line number, method names or class names out of this error, and I'm not sure where in the code this has been introduced.

Apart from going back on previous source code commits, or iteratively commenting out large sections of code, how do I work out where this problem is? Maybe there is a compiler flag that is more verbose about this error?

**UPDATE**

I did work out where the error was--a match/case where one of the `case` options was unreachable. I found it via trial and error, where it revealed itself as a more specific error after commenting certain parts of the code.

Unfortunately, the following did not help:

I tried adding the `-verbose` option to the `scala-maven-plugin`:

```
<groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3</version>
<configuration>
    <args>
        <arg>-verbose</arg>
    </args>
</configuration>
```

Also tried the `-X` argument suggested by edward.

Comment: I recall something like this happening in Intellij because of a name conflicts I had with the packages across different modules and projects I never really figured out why until I changed the names - everything was valid but it didn't like the 2 projects sharing a similar parent names : package myproject.a  & myproject.a.child

Answer (score 0):

Maven verbose output can be achieved with `-X` switch, like:

```
$ mvn -X compile
```

I don't know if can help here, but see if it works for you.